# Windows 8 Eclipse unable to link library C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows

I am trying to link a driver to my project in Eclipse. The driver has a header file "cassandra.h" and a library cassandra.lib . I am able to add the header file successfully in my eclipse. I have added the name of the library as "cassandra" in Libraries tab on eclipse as the screen shot below shows.

[image]

In Library Paths i am trying to add the location of this library. However my project still fails to compile. I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening.

[image]

The lib folder contains cassandra.lib and cassandra_static.lib. I have tried both files but it does not seem to work. The bin folder contains cassandra.dll. I have also tried to load cassandra.dll but in this case the compiler says "cassandra.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized". I had no problems loading these libraries in ubuntu.

Small program to test :

```
#include <cassandra.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    /* Setup and connect to cluster */
    CassFuture* connect_future = NULL;
    CassCluster* cluster = cass_cluster_new();
    return 0;
}
```

The error in compiling :

```
'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'
g++ -L"E:\cassandra-cpp-driver-2.2.2-win64-msvc140\lib" -o "simple.exe"  ./src/simple.o   -lcassandra
./src/simple.o: In function `main':
E:\workspace\simple\Debug/../src/simple.cpp:17: undefined reference to `cass_cluster_new'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [simple.exe] Error 1
```

Comment: What error message do you get from compiling/linking? Linker errors like "Unresolved external symbol"?

Comment: Did you tell your linker to actually use the library? Also I doubt that you had no problems using `lib` and `dll` files in ubuntu.

Comment: @Anedar: The error message i get is : make all 
'Building target: simple.exe'
'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'
g++ -L"E:\cassandra-cpp-driver-2.2.2-win64-msvc140\lib" -o "simple.exe"  ./src/simple.o   -lcassandra
./src/simple.o: In function `main':
E:\workspace\simple\Debug/../src/simple.cpp:17: undefined reference to `cass_cluster_new'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [simple.exe] Error 1

Comment: @Simon Kraemer: I think the linker is using the library with the -lcassandra flag and searching in the directory with the -L"E:\cassandra-cpp-driver-2.2.2-win64-msvc140\lib"

Comment: Sounds like a compiler-error. Is the function `cass_cluster_new()` defined in cassandra.h or an included header? Dont have the library here, maybe you have a link where i can find it?

Comment: Just saw your compiler-call. Looks good for the linking part. Maybe you forgot to include the path to cassandra.h in your include-paths. This would also explain the compiler error, but not why Eclipse doesnt complain that it cant find cassandra.h

Comment: @Anedar: the function cass_cluster_new() is defined in cassandra.h. The library can be found at http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/windows/

Comment: Jup, check your include-paths then. From what ive seen in your screenshots it should be the leftmost tab where your libraries/library-paths are. Include "E:\cassandra(...)msvc140\include" there